# Custom view made of multiple views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a set of views I want to always use together.  An example of this may be something like:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView />
    <EditView />
</LinearLayout>
```

The text view is a prompt, and the edit view is the answer.  I would like to give this combination a name, and be able to use that name to pop it into xml.  I'd love for it to be a custom view so I can put it nicely in a class and create various utility functions for it.  Is there any way I can do that?  I know I could subclass LinearLayout and create the children dynamically in the java code, but that loses me the ability to easily make changes via xml.  Is there a better route?

And yes, I also have places I want to do this which are more involved than just prompts.

Comment: shameless selfpromotion but might be relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722340/edittext-on-demand-widget

Comment: Have you read Android's article on designing [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)?

Comment: Yes i have Sam, and I've written 3 custom views in the past myself (a Camera View to show the camera, a UrlImageView to download an image from the web directly into an imageview, and a DragAndDrop image layout on top of AbsoluteLayout).  But none of the things in that page show you how to define a widget with subviews in xml-  they all do it in Java.  I wish to avoid that.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This example is for a horizontal number picker widget, but it's the same concept.

First create the XML layout for your custom component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_minus"
       android:layout_width="50dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="-" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edit_text"
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="number"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:focusable="false"
       android:text="0" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn_plus"
       android:layout_width="50dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="+" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then create the java class

```
public class HorizontalNumberPicker extends LinearLayout {
    public HorizontalNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizontal_number_picker, this);
     }
 }
```

Add whatever logic you need to that java class, then you can just include the custom component in your XML layout like so:

```
<com.example.HorizontalNumberPicker
     android:id ="@+id/horizontal_number_picker"
     android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height ="wrap_content" />
```

Check out this link for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

Comment: I tried this, letting Android Studio convert it to Kotlin first.  In the constructor I used 'this' for context, but I have no idea about the AttributeSet.  Just learning Android (coming from an iOS developer background).

Comment: If I understand this correctly, `HorizontalNumberPicker` has two `LinearLayouts`? It is itself one and it also inflates one in the constructor. Seems like one too many.

Comment: @rozina I think you can use the <merge> tag in place of LinearLayout in the custom component's layout file. That would eliminate the extra layout.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Compound controls](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound) for that purpose. There are a lot of samples and tutorials about it. Good luck )

Answer (score 1):

Put that XML into a layout XML file and inflate the view using an inflater when you want to.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_id, parent, false);
```

Once you have the view you can write a utility class that accepts this view and performs operations on it. Retrieve the text and edit view by using `findViewById()` or storing the references to those other views using the [ViewHolder pattern](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: Hmm.  If I was to do this in the constructor of a class derived from a layout (say LinearLayout), I could reference that in the parent xml, and pass this in as the parent.  If the top level xml of the child view was a merge tag it would eliminate the extra layout we'd otherwise need to shove in there.  And I could use the ViewHolder pattern as well for efficiency, but with the holder itself a View so I can avoid doing all the ugly tags.  I think this has potential, I'll test it later today when I'm back at home.