# How to make custom view ( imageview + progressbar)?

Tags: android

I want to display progressbar over imageView. Gennerally works nice if i do:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_holder"
        android:layout_width="120dip"
        android:layout_height="120dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Is it possible to combine it to single widget?

Comment: yes,  crrate a custom layout class by extending RelativeLayout

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978298/custom-view-made-of-multiple-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, just make a new class that extends `RelativeLayout` and inflate it like this:

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout {
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();

    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();

    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.myLayout, this);
        //Create your layout here
    }
}
```

Comment: that way you will end up with two RelativeLayouts in the view hierarchy

Comment: Yes. If that's a problem you can use a View instead of a RelativeLayout.

Comment: actually ViewGroup (FrameLayout for example),  not View as View cannot have child Views,  but still its one extra View in the hierarchy

Comment: do you have complete solution for this?